# Only one row is added from 2000+ rows in excel, while uploading it into django admin

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-templates

I have around 2000+ row in my excel file and while uploading the selected files its show only last row added to the Django admin. How to fix it?

**Here is my import.html(HTML FILE)**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_resource = ProductResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_product = request.FILES['myfile']

        if not new_product.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request,'Wrong Format')
            return render(request, 'Upload.html')
        
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_product.read(),format='xlsx')
        for data in imported_data:
            value = Product(
                data[0],
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
                data[6]
            )
        value.save()
    return render(request,'import.html')
```

**resources.py**

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Product

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

**admin.py**

```
admin.site.register(Product)
class PersonAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.simple_upload),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the save is outside the loop so it will only save once and it will be the last item in the loop, try:

```
    for data in imported_data:
        value = Product(
            data[0],
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
            data[6]
        )
        value.save()
```